# require(path.resolve(filePath)) to import statement

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, import, dynamic-import

I have autoLoad script for ExpressJS application written in JS and currently we are migrating to TypeScript

```
export const loadModels = () => {
  glob('modules/*/**.model.js', (err, files) => {
    if (!err) {
      files.forEach((filePath) => {
        require(path.resolve(filePath));
      });
    }
  });
};
export const loadRoutes = (app: express.Application) => {
  glob('modules/*/**.routes.js', (err, files) => {
    if (!err) {
      files.forEach((filePath) => {
        require(path.resolve(filePath))(app);
      });
    }
  });
};
```

How to change `require(path.resolve(filePath));` and `require(path.resolve(filePath))(app);` to `import` statement?

---

This is sample route file

```
import config from './../../config';
import express from 'express';
import QuestionCtrl from './question.controller';
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

export default (app: express.Application, events: EventEmitter) => {
  const questionCtrl = new QuestionCtrl(events);
  app.route(`${config.app.apiBase}/questions`).post(questionCtrl.create);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably utilize [dynamic imports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html). For example:

```
export const loadRoutes = async (app: express.Application) => {
  glob('modules/*/**.routes.js', async (err, files) => {
    if (!err) {
      for (filePath of files) {
        const route = await import(path.resolve(filePath));
        route(app);
      };
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Cannot find name 'filePath'.

for (filePath of files) {
              ~~~~~~~~

error TS1308: 'await' expression is only allowed within an async function.

   const route = await import(path.resolve(filePath));
                         ~~~~~

 error TS2304: Cannot find name 'filePath'.
     const route = await import(path.resolve(filePath));

Comment: Now got `TypeError: route is not a function`

Comment: What's an example of one of your route files? Depending on how things are exported in the route file, it may need to be something like `route.exportName(app)`.

Comment: I updated my code to include `async` on the `glob` callback - without it I'm not sure how you even got it to build. Does that fix it?

Comment: I fixed it my own and `TypeError: route is not a function` is the problem now